# Panda gym returning errors when running

Tags: python-3.x, openai-gym

I found a gym environment on GitHub for robotics, I tried running it on collab without rendering with the following code

```
import gym
import panda_gym

    env = gym.make('PandaReach-v2', render=True)
    
    obs = env.reset()
    done = False
    while not done:
        action = env.action_space.sample() # random action
        obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    
    env.close()
```

I got the following error

```
    import gym
import panda_gym

env = gym.make('PandaReach-v2', render=True)

obs = env.reset()
done = False
while not done:
    action = env.action_space.sample() # random action
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

env.close()
```

here is the library link:https://pypi.org/project/panda-gym
hope that i can get help